# Oracle database server on 64bit Windows 8.1

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have simple question. Is it possible to install Oracle 11g Express Edition on a 64-bit system? Me and my friends have a lot of issues during trying install it.

Anybody tried?

Comment: It must be possible, since they have it in download list. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: Yes, i know but as u can see in google people have problems with it. It is a little bit weird...

Comment: @m4rtin77 and *what* problem do you have? If you do not give us all the details (error messages etc) we cannot help you. Or do you expect us to google it for you and solve *all* the issues people have on the internet?

Comment: The simple answer is yes, but you already know that. If you have specific issues with the installation then you could ask about those, giving details of what you downloaded, what you ran, parameters supplied etc., and what happened. But it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: The error was 
"Error- Windows cannot find 'http://127.0.01:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. 
 Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again" 
I have found solution. Now I will try install HR user with default database for practise. Thanks for help. I am new here on StackOverflow :] I will use more search engine :]